# Principal eigenvalue of Laplacian under volume preserving mean curvature flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, eigenvalues, flows

Consider a compact uniformly convex n-dimensional hypersurface $M_0$ without boundary , which is smoothly imbedded in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ , and suppose that $M_0$ is represented locally by some diffeomorphism 
$$
F_0: \mathbb R^n \supset U \rightarrow  F_0(U) \subset M_0 \subset \mathbb R^{n+1} 
$$
We deform it by volume preserving mean curvature flow 
\begin{align}
&\partial_t F(x,t) = (h(t)-H(x,t))\cdot \nu(x,t)  ~~~~~x\in U , t\ge 0   \\
&F(\cdot, 0) =F_0
\end{align}
where $\nu$ is out normal vector , $H$ is mean curvature , and $h(t)$ is the average of the mean curvature on $M_t$
$$
h(t)=\frac{\int_{M_t} H d\mu}{\int_{M_t} d\mu}
$$
As  *Huisken, Gerhard*, [**The volume preserving mean curvature flow**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.1987.382.35), J. Reine Angew. Math. 382, 35-48 (1987). [ZBL0621.53007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0621.53007).   We know the $M_t$ converge to  a round sphere enclosing the same volume as $M_0$.

Let $V(t)$ be the domain enclosed by $M_t$. Consider the eigenvalue question.
\begin{align}
&-\Delta f=\lambda f   &x\in V(t)    \\
&f=0  &x\in M_t  
\end{align} 
Let $\lambda$ be the first positive eigenvalue. By the Huisken's theory, we know $\lambda(V(t))$ converge to $\lambda(B)$, $B$ is the ball has same volume with $V(0)$. And as in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177348/how-to-show-lambda-1-omega-ge-lambda-1b-when-omega-b) ,  we know  $\lambda(V(t))\ge\lambda(B)$. So, maybe, we have 
 $$
\frac{d\lambda(V(t))}{dt} \le 0 
$$
when $t$ is large enough. But I don't know how to show it. In fact , I do some calculation , and get 
$$
\frac{d\lambda}{dt}=\int_{M_t} \partial_t f \nabla f\cdot \nu dS
$$
$f$ is the eigenfunction of $\lambda$ and $\int_{V(t)} f^2 =1$. $\nu$ is the out normal vector. But,I don't know how  to esitimate $\partial_t f$ and $\nabla f $.

Comment: Can it be obtained by the monotonicity of the isoperimetric ratio and something like Faber Krahn inequality?

Comment: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Faber%E2%80%93Krahn_inequality

Comment: @PaulBryan  Could you talk about how to get the monotonicity of the isoperimetric ratio ?  In my view , I guess that is from Faber Krahn inequality. But I don't know the $\frac{d\lambda(V(t))}{dt} \le 0$ for all $t$.

Comment: I was thinking that the isoperimetric ratio $A^{n+1}/V^n$ is monotone decreasing along the flow and perhaps via something lie Faber-Krahn the monotonicty could be transferred to $\lambda_1$.